# SAP GUI Scripting Records Differently Between PCs

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

last week I asked a question about having issues running macros with SAP GUI scripts contained within on other people's PCs. I have gotten some updated information that I believe changes the question fundamentally so I will repost.

I made a macro series, one of which extracts data from the SAP system and imports it into Excel. While it runs smoothly on my computer, it begins going haywire the second it gets to a SAP GUI recorded script portion when used on anyone else's PC. At first I believed this may be an issue between servers but upon experimenting I have found the following.

I recorded this particular portion on three separate computers and 3 separate SAP GUI logins. This piece simply selects a specific field in order to input a particular number.

1. My Computer

   ```
   session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRIWO00-QMNUM").Text = Cells(i + 2, 5)
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRIWO00-QMNUM").caretPosition = 9
   session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[25]").press
   ```
2. Co-Worker 1

   ```
   session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt").Text = Cells(i + 2, 5)
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt").caretPosition = 9
   session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
   ```
3. Co-Worker 2

   ```
   session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
   session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[7]").press
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem "          2","C          6"
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").ensureVisibleHorizontalItem "          2","C          6"
   ```

Now as you can see, the first 2 codes are similar but with slight differences. Neither of these codes will run on any other computer besides the one that they were recorded on.

The last code is very different but runs universally on every computer. We are not sure why this is but I need the same capability to be able to create shareable macros for my company.

Has anyone seen this issue before? Does anyone recognize why these codes might be so different? Maybe a hidden setting?

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but I recently came across the same problem when I wanted to automate purchase requisitions (google lead me to this thread) and solved this by accessing the SAP elements not by findbyId but 'structurally' by finding them through the object browser and referring to the session's children.

This solution is a bit time consuming since you have to dig into the locals window and find the desired element you need each time. Below is an example.

I wanted to access the table of the purchase requisitions creation to fill it with info from an excel table. The SAP recording gave following when I entered some text "test":

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:3212/cntlGRIDCONTROL/shellcont/shell").modifyCell 0,"KNTTP","test"
```

I found that ID's with for example `/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/` can change according to SAP version or screen resolution.

So I searched in the locals browser until I found the table with the ID from the recording and wrote down (on actual paper) the tree of children to get to the desired element.

[Local browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU1kC.png)

The children of the session for this specific element are as follows:

```
Session
    1 - wnd[0]
        5 - usr
             2 - SUB0:SAPLEMEGUI:0016
                 3 - SUB1:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100
                     2 - SUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200
                         1- SUB1:SAPLEMEGUI:3212
                             1 - GRIDCONTROL
                                 1 - shellcont
                                     1 - shell
```

Then I wrote the following code instead:

```
Dim SAPitem As Object 
Set SAPitem = session.Children(0).Children(4).Children(1).Children(2).Children(1).Children(0).Children(0).Children(0).Children(0)
SAPitem.modifyCell 0, "KNTTP", "test"
```

This solution works with all SAP elements and all versions I have tested so far.
I can see how the ID's change through versions and screen resolutions but I would think the structure stays the same.

It's entirely possible to create a script that loops through the sessions and its children and returns the "location" but in the case of the table I needed there was no useful name in the objects fields to refer to.

Note: in the local browser the items start at 1 but the children start at 0.

Another note: I tried to loop through children to uncheck a list of checkboxes but this didn't seem to work.

I tried the following without success:

```
for i = 0 to 7
  session.Children(1).Children(1).Children(0).Children(4).Children(0).Children(i).Selected = False
next i
```

But had to revert back to the following code:

```
session.Children(1).Children(1).Children(0).Children(4).Children(0).Children(0).Selected = False
session.Children(1).Children(1).Children(0).Children(4).Children(0).Children(1).Selected = False
session.Children(1).Children(1).Children(0).Children(4).Children(0).Children(2).Selected = False
session.Children(1).Children(1).Children(0).Children(4).Children(0).Children(3).Selected = False
session.Children(1).Children(1).Children(0).Children(4).Children(0).Children(4).Selected = False
session.Children(1).Children(1).Children(0).Children(4).Children(0).Children(5).Selected = False
session.Children(1).Children(1).Children(0).Children(4).Children(0).Children(6).Selected = False
session.Children(1).Children(1).Children(0).Children(4).Children(0).Children(7).Selected = False
```

Answer (score 0):

From my recent personal experience, it is due to poor implementation/maintenance of SAP by your company. Assuming things were fine when you first adopted SAP, this may be due to non-universal updates. In my case, things are slightly different between menus. One window may automatically close on one computer but not another (workaround by using "on error," but this shouldn't be required). I would simply use the bottom scripting technique and attribute the two former to SAP configurations that haven't been updated. Your SAP development/maintenance team should be able to give you an exact answer, but if they are anywhere near as friendly/knowledgeable as ours: "Good luck"